# trying to disable touch screen via xinput against an Xwayland server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xinput

I'm trying to disable my touch screen via xinput, here's my output for the cmd:

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet stylus:16                 id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet eraser:16                 id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet cursor:16                 id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-touch:16                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I've tried running:

```
xinput disable [id]
```

for the ids 2,4 and 6

but I get the following error:

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  21
  Current serial number in output stream:  22
```

any ideas?

I'm running Ubuntu version 22.04.3 LTS